# Does the Enneagram personality test have any established benefits?

Tags: psychology

**Probably related:** What does Myers-Briggs Type Indicator tell about a person? ([LINK](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/575/what-does-myers-briggs-type-indicator-tell-about-a-person))

I know a few people who are quite "into" the Enneagram ([website](http://www.enneagraminstitute.com/)), including some family members of mine. I was sent a book on it recently from some of them. It's a personality analysis/self-knowledge type of system that has supposed benefits. From their FAQ ([LINK](http://www.enneagraminstitute.com/FAQs.asp)):

> **What is the Enneagram?**
>
> Don Riso has defined the Enneagram as "a geometric figure that delineates the nine basic personality types of human nature and their complex interrelationships."
>
> **What use is the Enneagram? How can it help me?**
>
> The Enneagram can be extremely useful to everyone as a source of self-knowledge because it acts as a kind of "mirror" to reveal features of our personality that normally are invisible to us. Most of the time, people function habitually, as if on "automatic pilot," according to the pattern of their basic personality type. Usually this allows people to get along well enough in their lives, but when their normal routines break down or the stresses of their lives increase too much, their normal way of coping also tends to break down or become dysfunctional. Seeing clearly what our habitual patterns are—seeing what we are doing and why we are doing it, and at what cost to ourselves and others—holds the key to our liberation. By knowing your type correctly, you are able to see yourself—to "catch yourself in the act"—as you move throughout the day. With this increased self-awareness, you are also able to avoid reacting in negative and potentially dangerous ways.

**So, is there any evidence to support the Enneagram, its method, its potential beneficial effects on the individual if understood/studied, etc.?**

Comment: Like the MBTI it's bullshit that sells well. http://www.skepdic.com/enneagr.html I didn't find much serious research after a cursory foray into the literature (most likely because it is so blatantly stupid and esoteric).

Comment: And my condolences that your family is into typology, the pseudoscience version of astrology. Alas the NeoFFI doesn't come with a book of cartoon illustrations and I know of no scientific personality system that has such appeal to people.

Comment: "By knowing your type correctly, you are able to see yourself—to "catch yourself in the act"—as you move throughout the day. With this increased self-awareness, you are also able to avoid reacting in negative and potentially dangerous ways."  While I doubt EPT has any special claim in this regard, ANYTHING that makes you more self-aware and willing to consider your own actions will have this benefit, so in a sense, I suppose it should have SOME benefit.  I'm not considering the potential drawbacks (stereotyping, self-limiting, etc.) here.

Comment: I know this is super old, but "any benefits" seems too broad. I know someone into Enneagrams that seems to be less anxious about interactions when she uses it. That doesn't mean it is right (i.e. able to make predictions). Do we call a placebo effect a benefit?

Comment: @Oddthinking: indeed, it has been a long time, which also makes it good to re-read it as the asker! I agree it's pretty broad and I'll try to think of a way to re-word it. I'd think any regimen which encourages introspection/self-improvement would generally have "benefits," so this is probably untestable (at least how it's currently worded).